# Track last time app/exe was launched on Windows

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a way to log two things: (1) the last time every program on the system was launched and (2) the number of times it was launched within some interval (e.g. 4 hour bins over several months). I want to use this data as a way to find infrequently used apps to uninstall, or to optimize launches of frequently used apps.

I'm not interested at all in how long an app is running, only the process creation event, but many app trackers are focused on time management and don't log this kind of data at all. I also don't want a log entry for every single launch (e.g. via procmon or secpol.msc auditing), that is a bit to heavy and would generate large log files. I don't even need time granularity, date alone would be sufficient, which would also reduces writes a lot, since many apps are launched multiple times a day.

I'm pretty sure Windows is already logging this kind of data somewhere (see [Activity history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/-windows-activity-history-and-your-privacy-2b279964-44ec-8c2f-e0c2-6779b07d2cbd)) for search suggestions and [telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/usage-report), so a way to read that data would be nice.

Comment: Windows 11 has a feature that can remove unused applications and files. Go to settings > System > Storage > Storage Sense. There are also additional settings for this under "Cleanup Recommendations" and "Advanced storage settings" under the storage section directly below the "Storage Sense" section.

Comment: What about running: `powercfg /srumutil` then create a pivot table in Excel from srumutil.csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `%SYSTEMROOT%\PREFETCH` to get a list of Binaries loaded & Executed recently.

Example:

```
DIR CMD*  
 Directory of C:\WINDOWS\PREFETCH  
10/27/2022  10:50 AM             2,627 CMD.EXE-89305D47.PF
```

This shows that CMD was last Executed on "10/27/2022  04:53 AM"

```
DIR SNIPPINGTOOL*  
 Directory of C:\WINDOWS\PREFETCH  
10/24/2022  08:44 PM             9,852 SNIPPINGTOOL.EXE-2DBBC209.PF
```

This shows that SNIPPINGTOOL.EXE was last Executed on "10/24/2022  02:44 PM"

The PF file format contains more Details which you can Extract using third Party tools.

More Here :
https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/win_prefetch_view.html
https://forensicswiki.xyz/wiki/index.php?title=Prefetch
https://www.hackingarticles.in/forensic-investigation-prefetch-file/
https://blog.group-ib.com/hunting_for_ttps_with_prefetch_files

Comment: This method only works if superfetch (SysMain) is enabled.

Comment: The forensicswiki link says there's a limit of 128 prefetch files, which may not be sufficient for long term logging, but I'll give it a try

Comment: Yes , there are "terms & conditions" but In Case it is already (or can be) Enabled , then it is free to use , instead of making some monitoring tool with automation , @CecilMerrellakabringrainfire

Comment: I think we can "increase" that limit , @goweon , using registry

Comment: Scratch that ! In newer Versions of Windows , the limit is already increased to 1024 !!

Comment: @Prem How exactly do you increase the limit? Which registry key? Do you have a source on that limit being increased to 1024?

Comment: Check https://www.inceptionsecurity.com/post/prefetch :: "In older versions of Windows, prefetch files were limited to 128 files. With newer versions, the limit was increased to 1024." :: I think 1024 is enough. Otherwise , you can monitor that Directory to track more than that.